# Change the label text using TkInter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm doing a simple algorithm for the 8-Puzzle problem, but I want to show it in a GUI.

This, is my loop to solve the problem:

```
while puzzle != puzzleGoals:
cont += 1
nRow = row(puzzle.index(0))
resolve(nRow)
```

**Resolve** is the function who do all the work. It's working fine and gives the right result.

I can create a screen with the order that I want

```
a1 = Label(root, text = puzzle[0]).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky= W)
a2 = Label(root, text = puzzle[1]).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky= W)
a3 = Label(root, text = puzzle[2]).grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky= W)

b1 = Label(root, text = puzzle[3]).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky= W)
b2 = Label(root, text = puzzle[4]).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky= W)
b3 = Label(root, text = puzzle[5]).grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky= W)

c1 = Label(root, text = puzzle[6]).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky= W)
c2 = Label(root, text = puzzle[7]).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky= W)
c3 = Label(root, text = puzzle[8]).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky= W)
```

[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkvTm.png)

So, how can I change the labels texts every time that's a new combination of the puzzle?
There's a possibility of a kind of "label.setText("abc")?
And how to input the root.mainloop() inside the while loop? Or its unnecessary?

Many thanks

Comment: Two ways. (1) Bind the `Label` to a `StringVar`, and then just call `set` on the `StringVar`. (2) Call the `config` method on the `Label` and pass it new `text`. [The `Label` docs in the Tkinter book](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) give examples.

Comment: You obscure the simplest way of configuring the label's text by _not_ keeping proper python references for the labels. Every variable in the 2nd example is assigned `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringVar and set it to the labels textvariable keyword then change text with StringVar's .set method